# Array sort by key where keys are clothes sizes (S, M, L, etc.)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array where it's keys are the sizes and values are either `'in-stock'` or `'no-stock'`.

Example array:

```
$data = [
    'L' => 'in-stock',
    'S' => 'in-stock',
    'XL' => 'no-stock',
    'M' => 'in-stock',
];
```

I'm trying to sort this by size. Expected output is:

```
$data = [
    'S' => 'in-stock',
    'M' => 'in-stock',
    'L' => 'in-stock',
    'XL' => 'no-stock',
];
```

I've been looking at other similar questions but with no success because those had different array structures.

I'm struggling with the `uksort` function since what I want is to sort the array and preserve the keys.

```
uksort($data, function($a, $b) use ($data) {
    static $sizes;
    // filter out only used size values => ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']
    $sizes = array_filter(["XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"], function($arr) use ($data) {
        return array_key_exists($arr, $data);
    });       

    $sizes = array_values($sizes);  

    if (array_search($a, $sizes) === array_search($b, array_keys($data))) {
        return 0;
    }      
    if (array_search($a, $sizes) < array_search($b, array_keys($data))) {
        return -1;
    }      
    if (array_search($a, $sizes) > array_search($b, array_keys($data))) {
        return 1;
    }      

});
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [S] => in-stock
    [L] => in-stock
    [XL] => in-stock
    [M] => in-stock
)
```

Im trying to compare key positions in `$data` and defined sort order in `$sizes`. It does not work and i'm struggling to fully understand how to properly compare `$a` and `$b` in the `uksort` callback.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

*The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a *definite order*, don't use it for sorting, but rather for mapping. E.g.:

```
$data = [
    'L' => 'in-stock',
    'S' => 'in-stock',
    'XL' => 'no-stock',
    'M' => 'in-stock',
];

function getOrderedBySize(array $data): array {
    $result = [];
    foreach (["XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"] as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $data)) {
            $result[$key] = $data[$key];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r($data);
print_r(getOrderedBySize($data));
```

---

Though if you absolutely wanted to sort the input array, this will do:

```
$fixedOrder = array_flip(["XXS", "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL"]);

uksort($data, static fn(string $a, string $b): int => $fixedOrder[$a] <=> $fixedOrder[$b]);

print_r($data);
```

Comment: your code will not work in small case please use strtoupper function

Comment: There's no indication in the question that lower case keys are a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `uasort` function (user-associative-sort), not uksort.

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a >= $b;
});
```

The function will receive two items.

So, in a more complicated case, say you want to sort rows of the format

[ 'size' => 'L', 'name' => 'Xyzzy' ]

you would do

```
uasort($array, function($row1, $row2) {
    $keys = [ 'size' => 1, 'name' => -1 ];
    foreach ($keys as $name => $order) {
        if ($row1[$name] < $row2[$name]) {
             return $order;
        }
        if ($row1[$name] === $row2[$name]) {
             continue;
        }
        return -1*$order;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

which would allow to sort one key ascending, then another key descending. You can wrap this in a different function:

```
function flexsort(&$array, $order) {
uasort($array, function($row1, $row2) use($order) {
    foreach ($order as $name => $order) {
        if ($row1[$name] < $row2[$name]) {
             return $order;
        }
        if ($row1[$name] === $row2[$name]) {
             continue;
        }
        return -1*$order;
    }
    return 0;
});
};
```

Then:

```
flexsort($allRows,[ 'size' => 1, 'name' => -1 ]);
```